# How to address QVGA (320x240) devices (HTC Wildfire, SE x10 mini, Motorola Flipout) in the xml files of Android?

Tags: android-xml, android, android-resolution

I found introducing a directory "values-notlong-ldpi" did not work out for me

**Solved it:** using -notlong-ldpi DID work. The mistake was somewhere else (the child overwrote the style info)

However, if u find a better way to address those devices, feel free to post it.

Comment: just found http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#QualifierRules My approach seems to be correct. Maybe the mistake lies somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it: using -notlong-ldpi DID work. The mistake was somewhere else (the child overwrote the style info)

Answer (score 0):

hey you can create layout-small folder under res folder and put xml files of small screen device(320x240) under it.

Comment: Hm, I dont like those "small"... attributes. As I understand they refer to the physical screen size not to the density. I think -notlong-ldpi targets the Wildfire in the best way